# Exporting 3D graphics from Mathematica to TeX

Tags: graphics, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

So far, whenever I had to use a 3D plot generated in Mathematica in a LaTeX document, I used exported the graphics to either of the following:

- PDF
- PNG

file format. Then I could easily include the graphics in my document. However, if the graphics is somehow complicated (for example contains several detailed surfaces), then this method produces poor results. By poor, I mean that either the `pdf` is of low quality, very "heavy" (i.e. takes long to load) etc. In case of the `png` option, then problems are clear; in particular the lack of scalability.

I'm interested in the methods you guys are using in this context, namely the workflow `Mathematica->Graphics Object->Export->Include in LaTeX document`.

Comment: To "lighten" the pdf, would flattening the layers help? Also, I'd think this might be borderline off-topic since it's about getting good graphics out of mathematica, rather than anything specifically LaTeX related...

Comment: @Seamus: I'm not sure I know what you mean with your hint. As for the nature of the question; well I disagree with you. I specifically refer to the inclusion of mathematica 3D figure in a LaTeX document.

Comment: Would you be able to post a Mathematica notebook `.nb` file that contains the generated graphic in question? I'm assuming the "heavy-ness" is related to the file size, right?

Comment: @Werner: More likely to the rendering complexity.

Comment: @Werner: I cannot provide the `.nb` file. Sorry. However, what Andrey wrote is the essence of the issue. I guess...

Comment: I think this is off-topic, so will close.

Comment: You may find [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/736/37) [helpful](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2176/7844).